# SQL statement to lookup ancestor for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables, one contains hierarchical employee data,

> Id, Name, ManagerId
>
> 1, Boss, NULL
>
> 2, ManagerA, 1
>
> 3, ManagerB, 1
>
> 4, LeadC, 2
>
> 5, EngineerD, 4
>
> ...

The other table contains who is the head of each department

> Id, Department
>
> 2, Development
>
> 3, Sales
>
> 4, ProjectX

Now I want to create a View based on the first table, but has one more Department column, determined by the nearest ancestor that has entry in table 2. Is it possible using a single SQL statement?

> Id, Name, ManagerId, Department
>
> 1, Boss, NULL, NULL
>
> 2, ManagerA, 1, Development
>
> 3, ManagerB, 1, Sales
>
> 4, LeadC, 2, ProjectX
>
> 5, EngineerD, 4, ProjectX

Comment: sorry to say but can not understand how you decide the ancestor ??

Comment: @AmitSingh by 'nearest ancestor' I mean look up parent chain recursively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a recursive common table expression will traverse the hierarchy

```
with ed as (
    select
        employee.id, employee.managerid, department.department
    from employee left join department on  employee.Id = department.Id 
    where department is not null
    union all 
    select
        employee.id, employee.managerid, department.department
    from employee 
    inner join ed on employee.managerid = ed.id
    inner join department on  ed.Id = department.Id 
)
select * From ed
```

answer adapted from http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you for the answer and the pointer to CTE, which I am definitely going to learn.

Answer (score 1):

```
select employeedata.id,name,managerId,
case when DepartmentName 
is null then (select departmentName from department where id =managerID )
else DepartmentName
end as dep2
from employeeData
left join 
department on employeeData.id=department.id
```

[see you sql demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/062d2/16)

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
SELECT e.*,
CASE h1.Department IS NULL h2.Department ELSE h1.Department END AS Department
from employee e
LEFT JOIN heads h1 ON e.id = h1.id
LEFT JOIN heads h2 ON e.ManagerId = h2.id
```